# I need to pull out $ figures from a column and move to another

Tags: excel

Here's my problem: Every month I download data from my eBay invoices. Some of the fields are very useful, but column B includes a bunch of information about the item. I need to break this column into four. Each item that need to be broken out is separated by a different separator; ;, :, and (). The

Here's a sample row of data - The information in the `()` below is what I'm trying to capture:

`Red Kitchen Sterilite 12 Qt Plastic Twin Sink Dish Pan Wash Tub Basin Laundry ;tippyice Final price: $17.99 (Store)`

- The first column to be the description (up to the word Laundry)
- The second column after the semi colon if for the buyer ID (tippyice)
- The third column would be for the price and doesn't have a seperator between buyer ID, but I could identify after the colon `$17.99`
- The fourth column indicating (STORE) is not needed at all.

Any suggestions on how to manipulate this data each month?

Comment: Record a macro for one month and you should be good to use it again and again. Doing text to columns on semicolon, colon and opening parenthesis sounds enough.

Comment: Check out the split() function.  This will get you the first column: Range("B1").Value = Split(Range("A1").Value, ";")

Answer (score 0):

These formulas will extract the data you're looking for (Assuming your data is in Cell A1):

First Column:

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(";",A1)-1)
```

Second Column:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(";",A1)+1,SEARCH("Final",A1)-(SEARCH(";",A1)+1))
```

Third Column:

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)+3,LEN(A1)-(SEARCH(" (",A1)+1)))
```

(VALUE function is included to change from a string into an integer in case you want to sum the column or perform other calculations)